# I want score attained by user

Tags: node.js, replit

I have to get score of user in my quiz.Here, is the link
https://replit.com/@ArpitKumar9/quiz-1#index.js

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an error with this package you use.
Node.js has a built-in core module for readline:
[nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/readline.html](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/readline.html)

You better use that instead.

An excerpt from node docs:

```js
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);

  rl.close();
});
```

Comment: I want to add options in this code. link is shown above